# Class 'Zend_Log' not found - SSH -reindexall for Magento

Tags: zend-framework, shell, magento

Just recently have become unable to reindex the Catalog URL Rewrites in Magento back office with Magento producing the ever so helpful error of 'There was a problem with reindexing process.' so I attempted to reindex via SSH using php ./shell/indexer.php -reindexall
 and received the following...

Warning: include(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/reprebat/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Zend/Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='"."      ') in /home/reprebat/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /home/reprebat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 247

There appears to be nothing out of the ordinary at any of these files/lines - just the default Magento file versions.

I have no idea when this problem occurred or this error was triggered - and unlike most other similar issues I found online, it often appears to be related to a 3rd party extension with incorrect method names... But our error doesn't even specify anything such as this - or anything of particular use to me.

I don't suppose anyone could advise of what this could potentially be indicating please? Any assistance greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is your php-cli related issue here. You have to verify if the php-cli configuration is up with your "magento" needs and all things in "PATH" are really there in the same way like they are for webserver php config

Comment: Expanding on what Anton said, it's likely to be the include_path that needs updating. ZF needs to be on the include path and you can see from the 2nd warning that the include path is empty. Compare the include_path var in the standard php.ini to the PHP CLI ini (which is separate) assuming that's the way it works in Magento

Comment: It looks like the include path is not being set by `app/Mage.php` as it should be. This file is normally included in `Mage_Shell_Abstract::__construct()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this eventually...

The .htaccess file included the following:-

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value include_path "."
```

By commenting out, like below, this rectified the problem and allows the indexer to run successfully again...

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
#php_value include_path "."
```

At this stage, I am unaware of any potential implications although considering the default .htaccess provided in the Magento 1.6.2 files did not include this, I'm under the impression that little will fail to function or break. I will update this answer with any news.